# GitBook offline editor: "Redirect from HTTPS to HTTP not allowed"

Tags: git, https, gitbook

I'm trying to learn how to use the desktop version of the gitbook editor. I've followed the instructions as carefully as I can, but when I try to push or pull to my github repository, I get the message, "Redirect from HTTPS to HTTP not allowed". I don't know what it means, and I don't know what to do about it. This kind of message shows up in a google search, but I can't find any mentions of it in conjunction with gitbook.

There's only one place where I've entered a URL, and that's in the book repository settings -- it points to my repo on github and it starts with https.

How can I fix this?

Edit: the URL in `Book->Repository Settings...` is `https://git.github.com/greatbigbore/HarryPotterBook.git` -- experimental; I'm not writing about Harry Potter. I also tried with camel case 'GreatBigBore' out of desperation. No joy.

Comment: What is the exact url?  Please copy and paste it into your question from gitbook

Comment: @TobyAllen Thanks for making me look at it. It got me wondering why the git.github instead of just github -- I don't remember where I pasted that from, but it was either github or gitbook, not something I typed myself. I took out the git and everything works fine now. Strange error message! Thanks for helping.